# How to make Apache2/Httpd trust all client certs

Tags: apache2

I have an apache2/httpd install on centos fronting a tomcat instance and I want it to trust all client certificates.

How should I go about it?

Comment: Fronting: what is your set-up (JK, Reverse-Proxy, ... )? Why do do you `require` client certs on the SSL connection if you trust them?

Comment: @BGR I'm using client certs for authentication in my webapp using SpringSecurity. In test mode I want apache to not look at cert chains.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as 'SSL Passthrough' with Apache since Apache needs to handle the SSL negotiation. Things I may think of are

- Do not use Apache but perform TCP forwarding, using a NAT rule for instance (`/sbin/iptables -I PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d test.server.ip --dport 443 -j DNAT --to :8443`). If you have two IP addresses assigned to the machine, your NAT rule can redirect based on the destination IP.
- You could configure a virtual host in Apache dedicated to test where you set `SSLVerifyClient`to `none`. This Virtual Host has a reverse proxy rule mapping directly to the non SSL http port of your Tomcat instance, or maps to the HTTP/S port and then you set the `SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile` with certs that Apache can present to authenticate to Tomcat